# Android Gradle: change the output name during the execution phase

Tags: android, gradle, groovy

The project consists of the several aar modules and the apk modules
The app module is configured before the library module, but app has a compilation dependency on the library modules.
One of the library modules calculates some rootProject.ext variables depending on buildVariant, so that those values could be shared between between all other modules.

Question.
I would like to reflect these values in the apk name, so that I could immediately know against which data is my apk compiled.

The following solution is not suitable

```
setProperty("archivesBaseName", "${myAppName}")
```

since the myAppName is dependent on the values which are calculated by the aar module.

I tried

```
task setApplicationName {
  doFirst {
    setProperty("archivesBaseName", "${myAppName}")
  }
}

preBuild.dependsOn setApplicationName
```

But the latest code did not change the apk name.
IS there a possibility to postpone the naming of the apk, during the execution or just before the execution of the module building ?